# Usage of the word "unlike"

Tags: word-usage

I want to say to a person that "I am not like him who waste one's time".

How can I say the same thing using the word `unlike` in my sentence.

Which of the following sentence should I say?

> 1. I am unlike you to waste my time
> 2. I am unlike you who waste one's time

Which one is the correct and is there any other, more native, way of saying the same?

Comment: ***Unlike** you, I don't waste my time.*

Comment: When you write English sentences, please try to capitalize "i", the personal pronoun.

Answer (score 3):

If you are blaming the person, with whom you're talking, then *ustanak* is correct...

> Unlike you, I don't waste my time.

However, this means that the person with whom you are talking *does* waste time.

If you want to say a general statement that is less insulting, you can use the following...

> I don't like to waste my time, unlike some people.

You still have to be careful when saying this phrase because, if you emphasize the word *some*, it can still sound insulting to the other person.

It's always more polite to talk about yourself and not speak negatively about  others.  If it were me, I would simply say...

> I don't like to waste time.